# handling non uniform tics in gnuplot

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

I am plotting my graph using gnuplot. I have problem that my data points on the x-axis are not equi-distant. So the shape of the graph turns out to be messy.As you can see from the plot the number on x-axis are 32,64,128,256,512. I want to have an equal distance between them. I am new to gnuplot I have tried different things but it is not working.

[image]

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you're looking for a log2 scale for x-axis

Comment: Maybe you could include reproducible code and data

Comment: Please include your data and the commands you used to generate the plot.  There are a few things that could cause tic marks like that, and without seeing your commands, we can't determine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone. Using logscale for x axis solved the problem. I am so dumb I didn't even thought of that.

set logscale x 2